# How to mathematically represent the $CSWAP_{1 \rightarrow 0,2}$ gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation, linear-algebra

[image]

The controlled-$SWAP$ gate represented in the circuit above can be written down by the following mathematical expression:
$$
CSWAP_{0 \rightarrow 1,2} = |0\rangle\langle0| \otimes I_{4 \times 4} + |1\rangle\langle1| \otimes SWAP_{1,2}
$$

Is it possible to write down such a simple sum of tensor products to represent the gate $CSWAP_{1 \rightarrow 0,2}$ in the circuit below as well? In particular, I would like to find an expression that still explicitly includes $SWAP_{0,2}$, so that I could implement any multi-controlled-$SWAP$ recursively.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to decompose SWAP in terms of Pauli operators:
SWAP=(I\otimes I+X\otimes X+Y\otimes Y+Z\otimes Z)/2.
So, now you can write
$$
CSWAP_{0\rightarrow 1,2}=|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes(I\otimes I+X\otimes X+Y\otimes Y+Z\otimes Z)/2
$$
Similarly,
$$
CSWAP_{1\rightarrow 0,2}=I\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I+(I\otimes|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes I+X\otimes|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes X+Y\otimes|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes Y+Z\otimes|1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes Z)/2
$$

If you desperately want to keep the explicit swap in there, then I'd rejig the notation slightly to mean $SWAP_{0,2}$ is the full 3-qubit operator. Then you can write
$$
CSWAP_{1\rightarrow 0,2}=I\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I+(I\otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes I)\cdot SWAP_{0,2}.
$$